# Scikit-learn dataset maker not accepting command-line arguments

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, scikit-learn, command-line-arguments

I'm working through a tutorial in Scikit-learn, and one section creates a dataset. This:

```
#Generate the example datapoints, red and blue.
X, t = sklearn.datasets.make_circles(n_samples=100, shuffle=False, factor=0.3, noise=0.1)
T = np.zeros((100,2))
T[t==1,1] = 1
T[t==0,0] = 1

#Seperate the datapoints by color.
x_red = X[t==0]
x_blue = X[t==1]
print ('shape of X: {}'.format(X.shape))
print ('shape of T: {}'.format(T.shape))

#Plotstuff
plt.plot(x_red[:,0], x_red[:,1], 'ro', label='class red')
plt.plot(x_blue[:,0], x_blue[:,1], 'bo', label='class blue')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc=1)
plt.xlabel('$x_1$', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('$x_2$', fontsize=15)
plt.axis([-1.5, 1.5, -1.5, 1.5])
plt.title('red vs. blue classes in the input space')
plt.show()
```

Makes a completely normal [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ygfd.png).

However, when I change it to accept command line inputs:

```
    try:
        in1 = (int(float(sys.argv[1])))
        in2 = (int(float(sys.argv[2])))
        in3 = (int(float(sys.argv[3])))
        in4 = (int(float(sys.argv[4])))
    except IndexError:
        print(
        "The program is run as: program.py a b c d \n"
        "a = Random seed\n"
        "b = Number of samples\n"
        "c = Factor\n"
        "d = Noise\n"
        "Example: python JISIDF-[01].py 1 100 0.3 0.1")
        raise SystemExit

    np.random.seed(seed=in1)
    #Generate the example datapoints, red and blue.
    X, t = sklearn.datasets.make_circles(n_samples=in2, shuffle=False, factor=in3, noise=in4)
```

Even when the inputs are the same:

```
don@don-DELL:~/Code/Tutorials/Peterrolelant$ python3 PeterNet-17.py 1 100 0.3 0.1
```

I get an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "PeterNet-17.py", line 27, in <module>
        X, t = sklearn.datasets.make_circles(n_samples=in2, shuffle=False, factor=in3, noise=in4)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/datasets/samples_generator.py", line 625, in make_circles
        X += generator.normal(scale=noise, size=X.shape)
      File "mtrand.pyx", line 1902, in mtrand.RandomState.normal (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:17755)
    ValueError: scale <= 0
```

This has been a problem before. How can I fix this?

Comment: `int(float(0.3))` and `int(float(0.1))` are equal to `0`. Are you sure that is intended?

Comment: If I remove the floats I get a value error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.3'`

Comment: So it's like this `in1 = (((sys.argv[1])))` ? That gives me a type error: `TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('<U1') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'`

Comment: That gave me a huge error:  A. `File "mtrand.pyx", line 965, in mtrand.RandomState.seed (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:11789)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` B. `File "mtrand.pyx", line 971, in mtrand.RandomState.seed (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:12055)
TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'`

Comment: Nope, Invalid literal `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.3'`

Comment: Oops. What about this: `in1 = int(sys.argv[1])`, `in2 = int(sys.argv[2])`, `in3 = float(sys.argv[3])`, `in4 = float(sys.argv[4])`?

Comment: Success!  Thank you!

Comment: Hey, can you put your code as an answer so I can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html and http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_circles.html, note that `seed` and `n_samples` need to be `int`s while `noise` and `factor` need to be `double`.

The main problem with your current type-casting is that `in4 = int(float(sys.argv[4]))` evaluates to 0 because `int(float('0.1'))` evaluates to 0, but `noise` (and `scale`) is expected to be greater than 0. This is why the traceback says `ValueError: scale <= 0`. For the same reason, `int(float(sys.argv[3]))` also evaluates to 0, but you probably intended it to be 0.3. Therefore, the solution for both cases is to remove the `int` casting.

The other minor issue is that you can just directly do `in1 = int(sys.argv[1])` and `in2 = int(sys.argv[2])` without casting the `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` strings to `float`s first.

Therefore, in summary, you should do this instead:

```
in1 = int(sys.argv[1])
in2 = int(sys.argv[2])
in3 = float(sys.argv[3])
in4 = float(sys.argv[4])
```

Comment: Excellent.  Saving this.